# What is the highest resolution of population density data that I can obtain for USA freely?

Tags: census, tiger, density, resolution, population

Ok so as far as my understanding goes the most high resolution dataset available that factors in many other things (other than Census data ) at a 1X1 km resolution is Landscan data created by [Oak ridge National Laboratory](http://www.ornl.gov/sci/landscan/) (ORNL). But, these are not available freely. What is the closest alternative you know of?

I am planning to use US Census Tiger data for 2010 and the lowest resolution it provides is of Census Tracts which are variable in their size (see [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html)).

Can anyone suggest me any other alternative (transformed) datasets ?

Comment: I am not seeing where to download population density shape files for census tract or census block. Can someone send me the link to a good source for this? Specifically I am interested in Washington DC, Virginia, and Maryland.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download Census Blocks from TIGER; you'll just have to download the data on a state-by-state basis and merge it all together.

EDIT: See [this page](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/pophu.html) for block-level shapefiles that already have the population and housing unit counts attached, so you don't have to deal with joining SF1 tables!

Comment: I have to still decide between the two, do you think it is possible to download all Census blocks for USA in one go?

Comment: The reason they're not available in a single file is the sheer size it would be. Some states one their own have nearly 500 MB of data at the block level -- and that's just the compressed shapefile! That said, it doesn't take terribly long to go to the FTP site (linked from the page I referenced in my edit) and right-click -> Save As for the 50 states. In my experience, unzipping the large states is the part that takes the longest.

Comment: There are approximately 8.5 million Census Blocks :-).

Comment: Yes there is a lot of data other than population i see..

Comment: +1 for merged files... having to put those two files back together can be such an (unnecessary) pain!

Answer (score 3):

If you need a gridded data set CIESIN's Gridded Population datasets may be of use. See   http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/gpw/aboutus.jsp#aboutTable for more details. The best resolution is 30 Arc seconds.

Comment: This is a very good dataset but the only problem is that 30 arc second is available for the year 2000, i think it will be a while before 2010 data at that resolution will be available

Answer (score 2):

Census.gov ->geography-> tiger data-> choose 2010 then use Web interface to download what you need,  that is for shape files,  for demographics you need to use the fact finder also on census website

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE, it is a best practice to include an actual Link to the websites you provide for in your answers.